# How to convert the values like xxxxxx.xxxx to xxx,xxx.xx

Tags: c#-3.0

I have some values like

```
882380.2634
2668927.957890
```

I need the format to be

```
882,380.26
2,668,927.95
```

So , how can I do it... any idea.. thanks

Any reusable code link will be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a format in the double.toString methods.

Something like:

```
double d = 2668927.957890;
Console.WriteLine( d.ToString("000,000,000.00") );
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine( d.ToString("###,###,###.00") );
```

if you don't want leading zeroes in shorter numbers.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx

Comment: Sir, I more question.. if the value after applying the formatter comes as .00 or .05 then I should display as 0.00 or 0.05 respectively.. how to do this.. any standard way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ToString()` method for this. Have a look at the [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 2668927.957890;
Console.WriteLine( d.ToString( "N2" ) );
```

The bonus of using a built-in format pattern is that it is culture-sensitive.

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)